# Steps to upgrade database from SQL Server 2005 to SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server-2005, sql-server-2012

Could anyone please help me out in knowing the step by step process to be done to upgrade the database from SQL Server 2005 to SQL Server 2012?

I already surfed about the process but I am not able to understand the complete idea and I don't know on how to start this process.

Could some one please help me on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is rather confusing with all different versions of SQL Server - the title mentions 2005 and 2012, the body 2005 and 2008 .....

Whichever : basically, you need to perform those steps:

1. Backup your SQL Server 2005 database (results in a `.bak` file)
2. Copy that `.bak` file to your new SQL Server 2008 / 2012 machine and restore it
3. Set the database compatibility level once you're on SQL Server 2012 using

   ```
   ALTER DATABASE (yourdb) SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 110
   ```
4. Done!

You can go directly from SQL Server 2005 to SQL Server 2012 - no intermediate step necessary (you cannot do this for SQL Server 2000 anymore, though)

Comment: thanks!! I need to upgrade to 2012 it was a typing mistake i made in the details mentioned in the body!!